# syncrhonize access on arrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

i have a function which inserts inside an arrayList strings passed as parameter.This function can be accessed by different threads,

```
public void adding(String newStringForEachInvocation){

             arrayList.add(newStringForEachInvocation);
}
```

i want to keep the `add` method concurrently and my doubt is, if two `threads` have got two differents strings is it possible for them to compete for the same bucket?

Another alternative is using the [blockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#put(E)) , but anyway it could represent a mutual esclusion for threads competing for the same bucket or not?

Comment: The blockingQueue is designed such that competition are handled. If you want to simulate the competition scenario then you have to manually code the mutex and semaphores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ArrayList is not thread-safe, and all the accesses to the list must thus be synchronized if it's accessed by multiple threads (explicitely, and/or by wrapping it using a `Collections.synchronizedList()`). Anything could happen if you're not doing it (data corruption, exceptions, etc.).

There are alternative, non-blocking List implementations, like CopyOnWriteArrayList. But depending on the use case it could be faster or slower than using a synchronized list.

Comment: Of course, it should be duly noted that when using the `.synchronized*()` wrappers, the user should ensure that the _same reference_ is used ;)

Comment: In your opinion, if i use a `hashmap`, not `concurrentHashMap`, as key the string passed, and value a `new Object()` , i could prevent  it?

Comment: A HashMap and a List are completely different data structures. It makes no sense to use a Map when you need a List, and vice-versa. An HashMap is not thread-safe either. The same answer would apply for a HashMap. This really smells like premature optimization. What makes you think synchronization is so bad?

Comment: well, real example. T1 and T2 want to insert a string concurrently, with list , as you said, isn't impossible to do without syncrhonization and i want that each threads have the same possibility to reach a bucket without blocking, so i theorized the idea to use a map, because a map can ensure ,more o less,  multiple insertions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collections.synchronizedList`, all unitary operation on that list will be synchronized

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)

Be careful though, if you are going to accomplish more than one operation on that list, like an iteration, use a `synchronized` block to ensure the integrity of the list, as specified on the javadoc :

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it